# Relationship between frequency and period of harmonic motion (free undamped motion)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. From $\frac{1}{8}x''+16x=0$ we obtain $$x=c_1\cos8\sqrt{2}t+c_2\sin8\sqrt{2}t$$ so that the period of motion is $\frac{2\pi}{8\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}$ seconds.
2. From $20x''+kx=0$ we obtain $$x=c_1\cos\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k}{5}}t+c_2\sin\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k}{5}}t$$ so that the frequency $\frac{2}{\pi}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{k/5}\pi$ and $k=320$ N/m. If $80x''+320x=0$, then $x=c_1\cos2t+c_2\sin2t$ so that the frequency is $\frac{2}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{\pi}$ cycles/second.

So I thought that theta represented the frequency of harmonic motion judging from the answer of question #1, but then in the second problem it seems that the period of harmonic motion is represented by theta.

To solve the first problem I did period = 2 pie / theta, but in the second problem I took theta since I thought theta was the frequency of harmonic function, but instead they did theta / 2pie. What does theta represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no theta ($\theta$) in that problem. I assume you mean theta to be whatever is being multiplied with $x$ in sin(x), cos(x).

Your confusion stems from not distinguishing *angular* frequency (radians per second, usually represented by $\omega$) and *linear* frequency  (cycles per second, usually represented by $f$). They are related by $\omega=2\pi f$. In an expression of the form $\cos(\omega t)$, omega gives you angular frequency, so to find linear frequency you must divide by $2\pi$.

Intuitively, $f$ is telling you how many full cycles are completed in 1 s (or whatever your unit of time is). However $\omega$ tells you what *angle* is swept in 1 s. To convert $f$ to $\omega$, you must multiply $f$ by $2\pi$ since there are $2\pi$ radians in a full circle.